# How to properly add a horizontal line to the ToC after all parts with adjusted vertical spacing (while using scrbook)

Tags: table-of-contents, koma-script, vertical-spacing

I want to add a horizontal line after all parts in my Table of Contents. I found that this is explicitly mentioned for the tocloft package on page 5 in its documentation (version of 10.01.2020) using:

```
\part{Part title}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\mbox{}\protect\hrulefill\par}
```

This also works for me using scrbook, but I am not sure if this is the proper way of adding such a line to my ToC as it adds a lot of unwanted vertical space between the part title and the horizontal line (see picture below).

How should I add such a line (using KOMA script and without modifying the ToC with the tocloft package) after all part titles and how can I change the vertical space between the part title and the horizontal line?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that there should be no page number for the part entries?

```latex
\documentclass[toc=chapterentrywithdots,numbers=noenddot]{scrbook}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy documents

\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  pagenumberbox=\linebelow
]{tocline}{part}
\newcommand*\linebelow[1]{\hfil \makebox[0pt][r]{\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\textwidth}{.4pt}}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\part{Catalytic Carbon Dioxide Reduction}
\chapter{Introduction}
\Blindtext
\chapter{State of Knowledge}
\Blindtext
\part{Next Part}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Works great - thanks esdd!
(and yes, there should be no page numbers for the part entries)